# Is it bitlocker secure?

Tags: windows, encryption, bitlocker, disk-encryption

I was thinking in the possibility to use bitlocker to secure the data of a drive in my computer.

But if I am not wrong, to encrypt the data, it is used a key that belongs to the user, so to can access to the data it is needed to log in with the user.

Well. If someone have access to my computer, I know that there are utilities that boot from USB and can change the password of the users, so only it is needed to change the password of the user to have access to the data. This applications are very easy to find and very easy to use, and also Microsoft has one utility for that.

So my doubt is, if someone has access to my computer, really does BitLocker help to secure my data?

Comment: Have you researched how bitlocker actually works at all?

Comment: The disk is encrypted. The utility you boot with is not able to read it to find the password and change it.

Comment: @DavidMarshall I understand that point, but what happen if my disk has two partitions, one for the system and other for the data and i only encrypt the data partition?

Comment: “If someone have access to my computer, I know that there are utilities that boot from USB and can change the password of the users, so only it is needed to change the password of the user to have access to the data.” - The minute someone did this, they would receive a prompt to provide the BitLocker recovery key. “What if I only encrypt the data partition?” - They would still need to provide they passphrase to mount the BitLocker protected volume, but seriously, encrypt both volumes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But if I am not wrong, to encrypt the data, it is used a key that belongs to the user, so to can access to the data it is needed to log in with the user.

Not exactly. It's **EFS** (the "Encrypt file" checkbox in Properties>Advanced) that uses per-file, per-user keys that are protected with your Windows account; whereas BitLocker uses a single key for the entire partition at block-device level.

> But if I am not wrong, to encrypt the data, it is used a key that belongs to the user, so to can access to the data it is needed to log in with the user.
>
> Well. If someone have access to my computer, I know that there are utilities that boot from USB and can change the password of the users, so only it is needed to change the password of the user to have access to the data

It isn't just "belongs to the user"; the EFS keys are themselves *encrypted with the user's password.* If you access that user's account through resetting their password, you will not be able to decrypt that user's EFS keys because they are still encrypted with the old password (which the OS doesn't know).

What you've seen those utilities bypass is just the regular access control protection, which isn't based on encryption but only on the OS enforcing the rules. (You don't even need any special software to bypass that.)

> So my doubt is, if someone has access to my computer, really does BitLocker help to secure my data?

Yes, and that's actually the whole point of BitLocker (and of EFS) in the first place. They work using a fundamentally different mechanism than the usual account-based file security that a live USB would bypass.